# How to set env variables to the redis.conf in docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, passwords

I have a very simple docker-compose config for redis:

```yml
...
  redis:
    image: "redis:6.2.5"
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
      - './docker/redis/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf'
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    command: redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
    networks:
      - network
...
```

In the example above I'm trying to set a password to the redis.conf, which contains:

```
...
requirepass {REDIS_PASSWORD}
...
```

but seams like it doesn't work this way. I know, that I can set password in the command line, but it's not about password. It's only an example. I'm going to set some other params and I want to be sure that they will be accepted.

What I did wrong?